# Why are cpu usage percentage different between top and iostat?

Tags: top, iostat

On a heavily loaded database server, I am getting vastly different output from `top` and `iostat` for cpu usage. Why might the value be different?

---

top:

```
%Cpu(s): 84.7 us, 11.8 sy,  0.3 ni,  2.4 id,  0.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.1 st
```

---

iostat

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          19.78    0.17    2.51    1.10    0.03   76.42
```

---

Note that `iostat` is reporting significant idle percentage and `top` is not.

Comment: I/O and CPU usage are not the same thing. Whatever it's doing is CPU-intensive but not very I/O intensive.

Comment: That is a true statement. iostat reports on both I/O and CPU utilization, this question is about the CPU utilization portion of the report. If I misunderstand the manpage for iostat, please clarify.

Comment: @ceejayoz please reconsider your downvote. As it appears you had a misunderstanding about the capabilities of iostat.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that on a single run of `iostat` the statistics reported are since system boot. `iostat -c 2 2` will report once since boot, then 2 seconds later with a second report since the previous.

In this case it matched closely with top.